# AWS Chime: Serverless Endpoint Security

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I am trying to setup AWS Chime for iOS application using iOS SDK using this as a [reference](https://github.com/aws/amazon-chime-sdk-ios). One of the steps is to [setup](https://github.com/aws/amazon-chime-sdk-js/tree/master/demos/serverless) a serverless meeting in AWS. All the above steps are successful. But upon creating the serverless meeting in AWS< the endpoint that I received looks like below:

**The issue that I am facing is that the endpoint is publicily accessible and anyone can start a meeting with this link. How do I control the host access in this endpoint?**

[image]